# How the heck do I do string comparison from a list item to the items in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-events, listitem

I am attempting to take the contents of an individual list items in one UL and when one is clicked add the value of that individual LI to an array and append the text string of the list item to an ordered list item somewhere else on the page.

I am having trouble comparing the string of the clicked LI,iterating through the array to make sure the string of the LI listed once, and then adding the text to the OL. Help appreciated.

```js
    var list = $('.list'),
    listItem = $('.list li'),
    container = $('.list-content ul'),
    containerItem = $('.list-items li');
    itemArray = [];

    listItem.on({

        'click' : function(){
            var current = $(this),
            currentText = $(this).text();

            if( itemArray.length <= 0 ) {

                itemArray.push(currentText);
                $('<li>'+ currentText + '</li>').appendTo(container); //add text to new area

            }else{
                for( var count = 0; count < itemArray.length; count++){
                    if( currentText === itemArray[count] ){
                        return false;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        itemArray.push(currentText);
                        $('<li>'+ currentText + '</li>').appendTo(container); //add text to new area
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }//end of click function
    });
```

Comment: Can you add some sample markup so we can see how this is supposed to operate? What errors are you getting? What is happening vs what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Depending on the content you have, you might want to put your text into an object rather an array with the text as property - this way you dont need to loop the array and eliminate duplicates automatically.

Comment: Thanks so much guys....here is a semi working example of what I am trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/im_cr/KGHxw/18/ .... you will see in the demo that I can keep adding items and I do not want it to do that....if an item exists on the second list I don't want to be able to add it from the first list....

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to check whether an object is present in an array

this should do

```
var list = $('.list'),
    listItem = $('.list li'),
    container = $('.list-content ul'),
    containerItem = $('.list-items li'), 
    itemArray = [];



listItem.on({
    'click' : function(){
        var current = $(this),
            currentText = $(this).text();

        if($.inArray(currentText, itemArray) == -1){
            itemArray.push(currentText);
            $('<li>'+ currentText + '</li>').appendTo(container); //add text to new area
        }
    }//end of click function

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yGSxk/)

Comment: or use ES5's `Array.prototype.indexOf`.

Comment: @Christoph old IE support issues

Comment: @Christoph Or rather use `$.inArray` because it won't fail in old IE. I know I know, who uses old IE anymore? And I know I know, you can use a polyfill. But when you have jQuery included, you "might as well" use `$.inArray` (I refuse to, but I'm just saying)

Comment: @Ian sure, it was just a sidenote to make people aware that jquery "is not" javascript - which sadly a lot of people think. Deleted the "rather" to point out the "one could as well - safely in 5 years" character.

Comment: appreciate the feedback...here is the link in my comment above with a semi working demo of what I am trying to do... http://jsfiddle.net/im_cr/KGHxw/19/ ...if an item exists on the second list I don't want to be able to add it from the first list

Comment: @Arun P Johny thanks for your help...that works perfectly and so simple. Thanks so much